# CNN ValueError when I try to fit my model

Tags: python, machine-learning

Here is my code :

```
from keras import optimizers from keras.layers import Convolution1D, Dense, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

model = Sequential() 

# my CNN layers
model.add(Conv1D(101, 101, strides=1, padding='same', dilation_rate=1, input_shape=(None, 120)))
model.add(Activation('relu')) model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same', strides=None))
model.add(Dense(2048)) model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(100)) model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_trainX_train, training_trainY_train, epochs=2, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv1d_8_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (27660, 120)`

Here is my training-set's shape : 
`training_trainX_train.shape = (27660, 120)` 
`training_trainY_train.shape = (27660, 101)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `model.add(Flatten())` will resolve this

```
model.add(Conv1D(101, 101, strides=1, padding='same', dilation_rate=1,       input_shape=(None, 120)))
model.add(Activation('relu')) model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same', strides=None))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2048)) model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(100)) model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

For more detail check https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6351

Comment: I have tried this. However, ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 101). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.